# Is it possible to horizontally center align a row of bootstrap spans that don't add up to 12?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>
</div>
```

I understand that you need 12 spans in total. Is there a way to still center align the two spans I have horizontally? The above will just float to the left.

I've tried putting a wrapper around them and margin auto'ng it but nothing happens.

I can go and remove the span class and just add a specified width but I need `span` class for fluid layout.

Comment: Well you could add the class `offset2` to the first `div.span4`... but when you shrink the window, it will not stay in the center anymore. (See http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem - offsetting Columns)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to center two columns of `span4` you can use offset param like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4 offset2"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>
</div>
```

Remember this may crash in lower resolutions. To prevent that think about using fluid grid layout. This is done by changing

```
<div class="row">
```

into

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Why would it crash on small resolutions ? Offset disappears and spans become blocks with the responsive design. For desktop, you do need to put that in a `.container` though (not necessary with the fluid).

Comment: what if your span totals are not even?