# Align three divs in center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I've following layout in bootstrap- fluid layout

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span3 offset1"> </div>
     <div class="span3"> </div>
     <div class="span3"> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My problem is i want to align all the three spans perfectly center aligned
As i am using fluid layout...in full screen above layout is perfectly aligned centre as i've applied fixed offset for the first div

But as it gets smaller in width. all the above 3 div's are not being perfectly aligned in center, as offset is fixed.

I think, here is what happening.....
in bootstrap we have 12 colums, all columns occupying 9 spans..remaining are 3 spans (odd)
because of that odd number i am not able to leave even spans on both sides.....

is there any solution for this?.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's spans are floated to the left. You can override this behavior by using this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="span9" style="float: none; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"> 
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">... </div>
        <div class="span4">... </div>
        <div class="span4">... </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be a row in there.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="span3 offset1"> </div>
       <div class="span3"> </div>
       <div class="span3"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A non-bootstrap way to solve this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3 offset1"> </div>
            <div class="span3"> </div>
            <div class="span3"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The width of the new element can be max-width with a static width aswell.

Comment: Now i Added row fluid in my layout...it solved my problem little, but 
three spans inside are not perfectly center aligned


Can you help!

Comment: Its because if you use 9 spans it will be one offset to the left, and two to the right. Try my new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
<div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span3 offset1"> </div>
     <div class="span3"> </div>
     <div class="span3"> </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
```

instead of :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

i think click on this below link duplicate question

[Is it possible to horizontally center align a row of bootstrap spans that don't add up to 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942858/is-it-possible-to-horizontally-center-align-a-row-of-bootstrap-spans-that-dont)

Comment: Now i Added row fluid in my layout...it solved my problem little, but 
three spans inside are not perfectly center aligned


Can you help!